# Function Pointer Array in C

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I want to make a function pointer array and be able to call them in a for-loop. How can I achieve this? I have tried:

```
void (**a) (int);
a[0] = &my_func1;
a[1] = &my_func2;
a[2] = &my_func3;

for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    a[0]();
    (*a[0])(); // Neither does work
}
```

But I am missing some syntax I guess:

```
error: too few arguments to function ‘*(a + (long unsigned int)((long unsigned int)i * 8ul))’
```

Comment: You should probably allocate some space for that array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the below code is what you need.

```
typedef void * func_pointer(int);

func_pointer fparr[10];

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
     fparr[i](arg); //pass the integer argument here
}
```

Comment: maybe a typo in the `typedef` statement, I encounter an error when compile the code, and `typedef void (*func_pointer)(int);` works. Pls double check:).

Answer (score 7):

The function you declare is expected to take an int as a parameter:

```
a[0](1);
```

Also note that you declare a pointer to pointer for the functions, but you don't allocate any memory for them (I assume this is only in the example) Otherwise it should probably be:

```
void (*a[3]) (int);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring that `a` is a pointer to a pointer to (or an array of pointers to) a function that takes an `int` as a parameter - so you need to pass an int when you call the functions, e.g. `a[0](42);`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Where have you allocated or defined array to store function addresses?

2) in loop you are always calling (*a[0])();,There should be loop counter

Answer (score 1):

You can `typedef void (*pfun)(int);` and then `pfun a[3];` is the array you want.

The following code may work for you:

```
typedef void (*pfun)(int);

int main() {
    pfun a[3];
    a[0] = myfunc1;    // or &myfunc1 whatever you like
    a[1] = myfunc2;
    a[2] = myfunc3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to give an argument to your function.

```
void (**a) (int); // here it takes an int argument
a[0] = &my_func1;
a[1] = &my_func2;
a[2] = &my_func3;

for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    a[0](); // here you do not give an argument
}
```

But be careful, you do not allocate memory to your `a` array, and it fails with a nice segmentation fault error.

```
void my_func1(int i) {
    ;
}
void my_func2(int i) {
    ;
}
void my_func3(int i) {
    ;
}

int main() {
    void (**a) (int);
    a = malloc(3*sizeof(void*)); // allocate array !
    a[0] = &my_func1;
    a[1] = &my_func2;
    a[2] = &my_func3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        a[i](1); // respect your own function signature
    }
    free(a); // it's always a good habit to free the memory you take
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your function-array with the needed size and initialize it with your functions like:

```
void my_func1(int x){}
void my_func2(int x){}
void my_func3(int x){}

void (*a[])(int)={my_func1,my_func2,my_func3};


int i;
for(i=0;i<sizeof a/sizeof*a;++i)
  a[i](i);
```

The address-operator '&' before any function-name is redundant.